# Url Amigavel Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-amigável

No **Codeigniter** existe um arquivo de configuração chamado **router.php** onde configuramos as urls amigáveis.
Na url do site que estou fazendo preciso deixar 2 parâmetros dinâmicos assim:

```
www.siteexemplo.com.br/parm1/parm2
```

Configurei o arquivo **routes** da seguinte maneira:

```
router['(:any)'] = "paginas/buscap1/(:any)";

router['(:any)/(:any)'] = "paginas/buscap2/(:any)/(:any)";
```

Isto significa que quando tiver o parâmetro 1 por exemplo na url o site vai redirecionar para o *controler* `paginas` no método `buscap1()` e nele eu filtro o parâmetro `(:any)`.

O problema é que quando a *url* tem o segundo parâmetro, o roteamento não funciona e o sistema só redireciona para mesmo método quando só tem um parâmetro.

Alguém já precisou fazer algo parecido que possa me dar um help?

Comment: Você está tentando passar dois argumentos no método `buscap2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Na verdade a configuração das rotas é feito da seguinte maneira:

```
$route['minhaRota/Testando/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'paginas/buscap1/$1/$2';
$route['minhaRota/Testando2/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'paginas/buscap2/$1/$2';
```

Tente alterar e verifique se funciona.